# Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineString to layer of type MultiPolygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, error, union, string

I´m trying to make the Union of two shapefiles on QGIS 3.28.9 and keep getting this error message:

> Feature could not be written to Union_8f811877_53f7_4317_ae22_fe05e7ab9695: **Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineString to layer of type MultiPolygon**
> Could not write feature
> Execution failed after 1.20 seconds

I don´t understand why because both shapes are polygons... (One of them is a buffer from a line shape)

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: It specifically says in the error that the type of the geometry is **MultiLineString** which is a line geometry not polygon. You must not be making the union on the right shapefiles.

Comment: I do not have any MultiLineString shapes in the table of contents at the moment. This has happened other times in the past 4 months.

Comment: I think that problem arise when two polygons are almost identical, or line up almost perfectly so the output is so thin it becomes a line. Try buffering one or both layers with a very small distance, and or Snap point to grid. Sometimes it can work

Comment: Yes that must be the problem, both shapes share some boundaries. Thank you, the buffering worked :)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem arise when two polygons are almost identical, or line up almost perfectly so the output is so thin it becomes a line.

Try [buffering](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) one or both layers with a very small distance, and or [Snap points to grid](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnappointstogrid).